# How to have same indents for individual bullet points

Tags: spacing, bullets

So I am writing my CV where each description for a job/experience is its own bullet point. Therefore, there are a few bullet points that I am creating using the `\bullet` keyword. My issue is that the bullets aren't alligning, i.e. they don't have the same indent. I would like to have three spaces (so using `\* \* \*` before each `\bullet`) but right now they are not in line with each other.

Is there something special I have to do so that each bullet point will be indented the same amount? They are not lists as each bullet is on it's own so my most favoured solution would be one where I insert some keyword before the bullet so it is all standardized.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newcommand\heading[3]%
{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE#1\\
\small\Letter\ \texttt{#2} \\
\small\phone\ \texttt{Phone} \\
\small \textifsymbol{18}\ 
\texttt{Address}
\end{tabular}%
}  
\newcommand\secline
{\tikz\fill[green,path fading=east] 
(0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,2pt);}
\renewcommand\section[1]%
{\par\bigskip
{\sffamily\bfseries\large#1}\\[-1.5ex]
\secline
}
\newcommand\cventry[3]%
{\makebox[19em][l]{#1}\hspace{1em}%
\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-6em}%
{{#2}\quad#3}%
}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\heading{Name}{email}{example-image-1x1.png} 
\section{Employment History}
\textbf{Job 1}, Employer 1 \\
\textit{City} \textbar \* \* 
\textit{Summer 2017} \\
\* \* \* $\bullet$ This is a job description for job 1. It was quite fun at times yet also quite boring at times. In short, this job was a job of contrast.. \\
\textbf{Job 2}, Employer 2 \\
\textit{City} \textbar \* \* 
\textit{Summers 2014|2016} \\
\* \* \* $\bullet$ In contrast to job 1, job 2 contrasted even more than job 1. While the highs were high, the lows were very low.
\section{Skills}

\* \* \* $\bullet$ Computer programming languages C, Java, Javascript, OCAML, and Python \\
\* \* \* $\bullet$ Statistical softwares R, SPSS, and STATA \\
\* \* \* $\bullet$ Mapping softwares ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro  \\
\* \* \* $\bullet$ Google Maps API, Mapbox API, and Openstreetmap API \\
\* \* \* $\bullet$ Microsoft Office Suite, Keynote, and LaTeX \\
\* \* \* $\bullet$ Professional and academic writing \\
\* \* \* $\bullet$ Customer service and sales 
\end{document}
```

In the sample code I have, this annoyance is visible with the bullet points for the job descriptions of job 1 and job 2. Specifically, the bullet for job 2's description is slightly to the left of job 1's. I have also tried using `\textbullet\` but that has also not worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Is there any reason why you don't use an `itemize` environment?

Comment: why not use an itemize list? The posted code produces the error: `LaTeX Warning: Command \textbar invalid in math mode on input line 46.

! Missing $ inserted.`

Comment: I would rather not use an itemized list because it then creates a large gap between the lines above it and below it. I like the vertical spacing between lines that is offered when just using the individual bullet. If there is a way to remove the line spacing that occurs during an itemize list however I would be fine with it. Also David sorry about that, it should be fixed now!

Comment: @ohhimark: For an `itemize` environment without additional vertical white space inbetween the items, use the `enumerate` package and `\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with itemize parameters set with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{wide = 1em, nosep}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newcommand\heading[3]%
{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE#1\\
\small\Letter\ \texttt{#2} \\
\small\phone\ \texttt{Phone} \\
\small \textifsymbol{18}\
\texttt{Address}
\end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand\secline
{\tikz\fill[green,path fading=east]
(0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,2pt);}
\renewcommand\section[1]%
{\par\bigskip
{\sffamily\bfseries\large#1}\\[-1.5ex]
\secline
}
\newcommand\cventry[3]%
{\makebox[19em][l]{#1}\hspace{1em}%
\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-6em}%
{{#2}\quad#3}%
}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}

\heading{Name}{email}{example-image-1x1.png}
\section{Employment History}
\textbf{Job 1}, Employer 1 \\
\textit{City} \textbar \* \*
\textit{Summer 2017}% \\
%\* \* \* $\bullet$ This is a job description for job 1. It was quite fun at times yet also quite boring at times. In short, this job was a job of contrast.. \\
\begin{itemize}
\item This is a job description for job 1. It was quite fun at times yet also quite boring at times. In short, this job was a job of contrast.
\end{itemize}
\textbf{Job 2}, Employer 2 \\
\textit{City} \textbar \* \*
\textit{Summers 2014|2016} %\\
%\* \* \* $\bullet$ In contrast to job 1, job 2 contrasted even more than job 1. While the highs were high, the lows were very low.
\begin{itemize}
       \item In contrast to job 1, job 2 contrasted even more than job 1. While the highs were high, the lows were very low.
\end{itemize}
\section{Skills}
\begin{itemize}
       \item Computer programming languages C, Java, Javascript, OCAML, and Python
       \item Statistical softwares R, SPSS, and STATA
       \item Mapping softwares ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro
       \item Google Maps API, Mapbox API, and Openstreetmap API
       \item Microsoft Office Suite, Keynote, and LaTeX
       \item Professional and academic writing
       \item Customer service and sales
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]